# RGBA color gradient with two extremes

Tags: leaflet, heatmap, rgba

This is an artistic and philosophical question as much as a programming one. I'm using leaflet to create a heatmap layer. Normally heatmaps depict intensity of a quantity.

The thing is, in this heatmap, I am color mapping values in the range [0,1] - and I want both values close to zero and values close to 1 to appear "hot" and values around 0.5 to be neutral or "cool". In addition, I want to be able to visually distinguish a "hot" zero from a "hot" 1, i.e, a distinct but complimentary color gradients from [0,0.5] and [0.5,1].

How can I do this properly?

Below is a sample gradient, it provides an idea of what I mean, yet it is from ideal. Curiously, if I set the opacity to 0 I get a darkish gray color - it would be great to instead have almost transparent colors around the 0.5 area. Any ideas?

```
gradient: {
                0.00 :'rgba(0,0,238,1)',
                0.05 :'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)',
                0.10 :'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)',
                0.15: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.2)',
                0.20: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.2)',
                0.25: 'rgba(238,18,137,0.2)',
                0.30: 'rgba(205,0,205,0.2)',
                0.35: 'rgba(178,58,238,0.1)',
                0.40: 'rgba(154,50,205,0.1)',
                0.45: 'rgba(240,255,255,0.1)',
                0.50: 'rgba(240,255,255,0.1)',
                0.55: 'rgba(240,255,255,0.1)',
                0.60: 'rgba(0,255,0,0.1)',
                0.65: 'rgba(0,255,0,0.1)',
                0.70: 'rgba(0,255,0,0.2)',
                0.75: 'rgba(255,255,0,0.2)',
                0.85: 'rgba(255,255,0,0.2)',
                0.90: 'rgba(255,255,0,0.5)',
                0.95: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)',
                1.00: 'rgba(255,0,0,1)'
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a *divergent* color scheme. Go to [ColorBrewer](http://colorbrewer2.org/), select "diverging" data, and select a color scheme.